# Better way to fetch parent record by few entries

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlperformance

I have a view that represent relations between publishers and literature (books,Magazines etc).

I am trying to fetch publisher id that publish a Book X and Publication Y.
So for example to find publisher/s that are publishing `Book#Clarissa` and `Publication#On the Nature of Things` - the result is publisher_id `1,5` (but not `4`).

I will do it by inner join the same view:

```
select *
from relations publication
inner join relations books on publication.publisher_id = books.publisher_id
where books.publication_type='Book'
  and books.extended_field_3='Clarissa'
  and publication.publication_type='Publication'
  and publication.extended_field_4='On the Nature of Things'
```

Things get complicated when I need to fetch by Book, Publication, Magazine (3 inner joins on a complex view).

Is there a better way? (Oracle specific can also help)

```
drop table relations;

CREATE TABLE relations
(
  publisher_id int,
  publication_id varchar(255),
  publication_type varchar(255),
  extended_field_1 varchar(255),
  extended_field_2 varchar(255),
  extended_field_3 varchar(255),
  extended_field_4 varchar(255)  
); 

insert into relations values(1,A,'Book','','','Clarissa','' );  
insert into relations values(1,B,'Publication','','','','On the Nature of Things' );
insert into relations values(1,C,'Book','','','Frankenstein','' );
insert into relations values(3,D,'Book','','','','' );
insert into relations values(3,E,'Publication','','','','A Paradoxical Ode' );
insert into relations values(4,F,'Magazine','Time','','','' );
insert into relations values(4,G,'Book','','','Clarissa','' );  
insert into relations values(4,H,'Publication','','','','Human Chemistry' );
insert into relations values(4,I,'Book','','','The Woman in White','' );
insert into relations values(5,K,'Book','','','Clarissa','' );  
insert into relations values(5,L,'Publication','','','','On the Nature of Things' );
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server?  The syntax suggests SQL Server.

Comment: Oracle, syntax Is just for the example Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not like to have a model that uses `extended_field_1` to `extended_field_4`, but your query looks fine.

Create a separate [index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm) for each `extended_field` that you use as condition to improve performance of your search.